# RPR material not rendering in preview

Tags: radeon-prorender-render-engine

I've installed and activated ProRender engine, but materials won't render even in a basic setup. However from the materials side pane it looks like it can render it correctly.
I'm running macOS Big Sur on MacBook Pro 2020 (cpu only).

Edit: rendering of the image works... only render preview does not

Many thanks for your help!

[image: missing material]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Sure, https://www.dropbox.com/s/qojw7ixv7lx3kqy/prorender-missing-material.blend Thanks!

Comment: Actually, rendering of the image works... only render preview does not

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Disabling `Viewport Denoising and Upscaling` in `Render Properties → Sampling → Viewport & Preview Sampling` does the trick. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯